# Fields erased in post

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an application in asp.net with some fields. I have the "name" field that is empty, I request that it be filled. But when the user clicks the "record" button is an asp button, the field is cleared every time after validation. I do not want to validate with javascript. How to cancel this procedure and leave the populated after validation without having to repopulate the field to be validated? I'm not using asp textbox. I'm using inputs type text.

Comment: Can u post some code? ASPX markup for the field and code-behind that does validation

Answer (score 0):

Make your input box serverside as `<asp:TextBox ID="tbxName" runat="server" />` instead of regular HTML `<input>` box.  boxes will get cleared after postback because they are not server side and so VIEWSTATE wont save their properties when a postback occurs.